# Define sequence generator in base class of JPA entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

is it possible to inherit the sequence generator of a base class in an jpa2.0 entity? The aim of this is to have the id property of all entities in a common base class and each entity just have to define the name of its own sequence.

This is what i want: Base class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "mySeqGenerator")
   Long id;
}
```

and an implementation

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator( name = "mySeqGenerator", sequenceName = "the_seq" )
public class MyEntity extends BaseClass {
   [..]
}
```

I'm using hibernate and is revokes this by "HHH000138: Mixing inheritance strategy in a entity hierarchy is not allowed, ignoring sub strategy in MyEntity"

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: do you want to generate ID for subclass despite the ID generated for the superclass? But... why? ;-)

Comment: And a side note - any annotations on non-entity or non-mapped-superclass are to be ignored by the JPA provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All generators are **global to the Persistence Unit** despite way how they were defined (in annotations on class level, field level or in `orm.xml`).

Therefore, you don't need to "inherit" or "share" anything - you can just use it.

Comment: Well, i think you are right, My intension seems to be very senseless =) I have to create a generator for each sequence.

Comment: You can also reuse the same sequence by many entities if this would help you in any way.